# Recording excel using HP Loadrunner

Tags: excel, recording

I have to record a flow in excel version 2007 using HP Loadrunner 11.0.
I am unable to record as the number of events is '0'. And, on other machines I am unable to open excel. 
Settings used - Win32 applications-->Giving MSexcel path from Program files and using protocol Web (HTTP/HTML) recording mode.

Can some one please suggest if this is possible and what should be my steps to proceed. And, if excel 2010 is compatible with HP Loadrunner 11.0.

Appreciate your timely response to the above query.

Answer (score 0):

- What server type does your Excel workflow app communicate with?    You have indicated that you have selected web/http, but is this the server type?   Excel could be pulling data from files, direct to database connections, etc...Have you confirmed that the requests are being handled by a web server or via web services?
- There are many ways to setup the recording options, some of which are antagonistic to any application type except a browser. How have you setup VUGEN to record an external application which is not a browser which communicates with a web server?

Twitter: @PerfBytes